# Matlab - How to apply low pass and high pass filters using fft2 and fftshift?

Tags: matlab, fft, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter

I am not sure how to apply low-pass and high-pass filters on a jpg image.

The filters are calculated by:

```matlab
function [cL,cH] = getfilters(radius)
    [x,y] = meshgrid(-128:127,-128:127);
    z = sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
    cL = z < radius;
    cH = ~cL;
end
```

so to filter the image, I have:

```matlab
img = imread('a jpg image')
ft = fftshift(fft2(img));
[cL, cH] = getfilters(40);
l_ft = ft .* cL;
h_ft = ft .* cH;
low_filtered_image = ifft2(ifftshift(l_ft), 'symmetric');
high_filtered_image = ifft2(ifftshift(h_ft), 'symmetric');
```

To display the filtered inverse Fourier transform:

```matlab
low_f = uint8(abs(low_filtered_image));
high_f = uint8(abs(high_filtered_image));
figure, imshow(low_f); figure, imshow(high_f);
```

This is the output:

[image]
[image]

If this code is wrong, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Why do you think the code is wrong? This seems like a correct low pass and high pass image. For display of the high pass image you might want to stretch the image so that negative values are shown as well (instead of taking the absolute value).

Comment: @CrisLuengo thanks for checking. Stretching the image was a good point.